# What is CPU I/O here?

Tags: performance, cpu-usage

I am doing performance improvements in an asp.net app.

A PDF generation action got my attention, since the total time elapsed for the request high and CPU usage was high when multiple request issued by fiddler.

When running CPU profiler using Visual Studio 2019 I got this report. What is the "Green" piece in the pie chart? File system is Blue what does the green IO represent in CPU profiler?

[image]